# How to add files from .gitnore folder back into project

Tags: git, intellij-idea2017

I have several files that are hidden in Intellij 2017. It seems that the hidden files are in the .gitignore folder. I need those files. So I'm wanting to know how to add those files back into my project, and remove from .gitignore folder. The only search results I have seen is how to remove a file which will completely remove the files from my project.

Comment: out of curiosity, which are the ignored files that you feel you need in your source control ?

Comment: A few are my thymeleaf templates and the others are my model classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the quote from [git document](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_pattern_format):

> An optional prefix "!" which negates the pattern; any matching file
>   excluded by a previous pattern will become included again. An optional
>   prefix "!" which negates the pattern; any matching file excluded by a
>   previous pattern will become included again. It is not possible to
>   re-include a file if a parent directory of that file is excluded. Git
>   doesn’t list excluded directories for performance reasons, so any
>   patterns on contained files have no effect, no matter where they are
>   defined. Put a backslash ("\") in front of the first "!" for patterns
>   that begin with a literal "!", for example, "!important!.txt".

Example:

```
$ cat .gitignore
vmlinux*
$ ls arch/foo/kernel/vm*
arch/foo/kernel/vmlinux.lds.S
$ echo '!/vmlinux*' >arch/foo/kernel/.gitignore
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I appreciate your help.

Comment: It was my pleasure :)

Answer (score 1):

A "clean explicit solution" I like to use is :

1st create a commit that removes (or comments out) the ignored paths from the .gitignore file.

2nd, create a commit to add all the files that are now not ignored in your working tree.

Of course this is to execute from a station that actually *has* the files you want to add into your git source control.

---